# "gnutls_handshake() failed" while downloading software

Tags: apt

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04. Now I am facing some problems while trying to install new software (tried via synaptic package manager and apt-get). This is the error I am getting in synaptic when I try to install unrar:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/unrar-free/unrar-free_0.0.1+cvs20071127-2_amd64.deb
  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
```

I am **not able to install any new software** and when I give "sudo apt-get update", I get so many errors all stating that handshake failed.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? What's the output of `sudo apt-get -o Debug::Acquire::http=true update`

Comment: ya I am behind a proxy. That problem is in my office computer. I will tel you the output tomorrow .

Comment: I am getting soooooo many lines of output for that command and finally it tells me the same thing -  W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/.../..  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a silly mistake. I was using the wrong port number in apt-conf file for apt-get. 
Once I changed it to correct port number the error got rectified!